# 403 Forbidden on virtual host with mod_rewrite

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp, mod-rewrite

I managed to install virtual host on LAMP server and created the config file 
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.com.conf`

```
<Directory /home/ihab/Workspace/Webdev/site.com/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.com
        ServerAlias www.site.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/ihab/Workspace/Webdev/site.com/public_html

        ErrorLog /home/ihab/Workspace/Webdev/site.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/ihab/Workspace/Webdev/site.com/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

While I have mod_rewrite enabled I did link my virtual host file from the sites-available directory to the sites-enabled directory:

```
sudo a2ensite site.com.conf
```

and added the assigned virtual host domain to my host file `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1       site.com
127.0.1.1       www.site.com
```

I checked `/site.com` folder permission, reported as following:

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 18 13:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 ihab     www-data 4096 Jul 23 19:16 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 18 13:56 logs
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 23 17:21 public_html
```

I went to my file explorer and discovered that directory `site.com` has **lock icon** while I have 403 Forbidden error when I go to `site.com` in browser.
Any help solving the issue is much appeciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may have its root in various causes, here are the solutions for two of them:

### Folder and File Permissions

Not only the site.com folder, but also all parent folders need to have their permissions set so apache can traverse them. Please check if /home, /home/ihab, /home/ihab/Workspace and /home/ihab/Workspace/Webdev do have proper settings.
They either need to either

- belong to the user as which apache runs (`chown www-data:ihab` - but that would prohibit you from modifying them if you do not pay close attention to their `chmod`)
- their group has to be the one that the apache2 user has (`chown ihab:www-data`, that would work)
- or you need to make sure the user **www-data** is in the group that those folders belong to (`gpasswd -a www-data ihab` or `gpasswd -a www-data users` for example)

### Apache2 Grants

Under "normal" circumstances the webroot belongs at `/var/www` - for these folders the "grant" are set accordingly by the apache2 default configuration. You chose to have the files in another folder structure - which is fine but needs some tweaking:
add `require all granted` to those folders:

```
<Directory /home>
require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ihab>
require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ihab/Workspace>
require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ihab/Workspace/Webdev>
require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ihab/Workspace/Webdev/site.com>
require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ihab/Workspace/Webdev/site.com/public_html>
require all granted
</Directory>
```